# Issue in bind DataGridViewComboBoxCell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I need help to fix my code:

```
for (int P = 0; P < DataGridView.Rows.Count - 0; P++)
{
  TNTDATADataContext Context = new TNTDATADataContext();
  var q = (from C in Context.Customers
           where C.Code == Code.Text && C.CompanyId == CompanyId
           join TP in Context.TourProgrammes on C.PackageId equals TP.Id
           select new { TP.DayId, TP.FromCityId, TP.ToCityId, TP.Programme }).First();
           DataGridViewComboBoxCell DaysComboBoxCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)DataGridView.Rows[P].Cells[0];
           DaysComboBoxCell.Value = (object)q.DayId;
           DataGridViewComboBoxCell FromCityComboBoxCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)DataGridView.Rows[P].Cells[1];
           FromCityComboBoxCell.Value = (object)q.FromCityId;
           DataGridViewComboBoxCell ToCityComboBoxCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)DataGridView.Rows[P].Cells[2];
           ToCityComboBoxCell.Value = (object)q.ToCityId;
           DataGridView["Programme", P].Value = (object)q.Programme;
}
```

This code is working well and bind a single value in DataGridViewComboBoxCell  which I have bind by code.

There is a first snapshot

[image: first snapshot]

There you can see a area of tour programme where are 3 DataGridViewComboBoxCell in a DataGridView this is a before loading Customer Detail Snapshot now I've load a Customer Tour Details after entering code in Customer Code `TextBox` Filed it showing all details but not showing rest of tour programme list in DataGridView its showing result in this second snapshot

[image: second snapshot]

I want a result like this third snapshot which I'm making manually for you can understand how can I want result after loading customer Tour detail's

[image: third snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int P = 0; P < DataGridView.Rows.Count - 0; P++)
```

DataGridView.Rows.Count happens to be the row number of current DataGridView, and its value is 1.

Maybe you should get the row number from `Context`

Comment: if i set the value 1 then DataGridView count was not working. which data you are seen in second snapshot that was coming after set value 0 in loop